# Integrating Pusher with data in a HTML table on Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pusher

We are evaluating Pusher http://pusher.com for a specific need. A user selects multiple rows in a HTML table tied to an Angular.js model, and these are background processed by a Rails application. I understand Rails 4 Live Streaming could also be used to do the same thing.

The status and some other fields are updated in a SQL table by the Rails backend. When the page is first loaded the **$scope.assays** variable is updated from a http call. This is then looped through to populate the table.

How can Pusher update the individual cells in the table as each row has completed processing? Will the code need to loop through a new $scope.assays variable and reload every cell?

Ideally we would like to just update the cell where the change has been made (eg: status on row 3),and if possible apply a CSS class to make the cell glow for a moment.

Sample code -

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="assay in assays">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selected" ng-checked="isSelected(assay.id)" ng-click="updateSelection($event, assay.id)"/> 
    </td>
    <td key="id">{{assay.id}}</td>
    <td key="source">{{assay.source}}</td>
    <td key="status">{{assay.status}}</td>
    <td key="chrom">{{assay.chrom}}</td>
    <td key="chrom_start">{{assay.chrom_start}}</td>
    <td key="chrom_end">{{assay.chrom_end}}</td>
    <td key="gene">{{assay.gene}}</td>
    <td key="cosmic_mut_id">{{assay.cosmic_mut_id}}</td>
    <td key="primer_left">{{assay.primer_left}}</td>
    <td key="primer_right">{{assay.primer_right}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pusher**

> How can Pusher update the individual cells in the table as each row
>   has completed processing?

[`Pusher`](http://pusher.com) won't need to do this - it's a job for JS. Pusher just connects (via websocket) to the pusher server & "listens" to updates you send from your app:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert('An event was triggered with message: ' + data.message);
});
```

---

**Function**

You'll be better using a separate function to go through the table, populating as required:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', populate_table(data));

function populate_table(data) {
     var row = document.getElementById("row_id");
     //do what you need with row to append data
};
```

Hope this helps?